# If $f(x) = \frac{4^x}{4^x+2},$ find the value of $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{1999} f\left(\frac{i}{1999}\right) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> If
>   $$f(x) = \frac{4^x}{4^x+2} $$
>   then find the value of
>   $$f\left(\frac{1}{1999}\right) + f\left(\frac{2}{1999}\right) + f\left(\frac{3}{1999}\right) +\cdots+f\left(\frac{1999}{1999}\right).$$

I tried it by changing expression to 
$$f(x) =1 - \frac{2}{4^x+2}$$
but I am not able to cancel any term.

Is there is any other trick to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm.. If $z = 4^{1/1999},$ then the sum can be rewritten as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{1999} \frac{z^i}{z^i+2}.$

Comment: @vikii did you find this question in Arihant Differential calculus?

Comment: @5tom what is that?

Comment: answer is $999+\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: This is not a popularity contest. Relax

Comment: @JeremyCarlos I intended that as a compliment to you. So, your comment comes to me as rather rude.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Hint:**

Observe

$$f(x)+f(1-x)=1$$

So, $$\begin{align}&f\left(\dfrac 1 {1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac 2 {1999}\right)+ \cdots+f\left(\dfrac{1998}{1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{1999}{1999}\right)\\&=f\left(\dfrac 1 {1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{1998}{1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac 2 {1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac {1997} {1999}\right)+\cdots +f\left(\dfrac{999}{1999}\right)+f\left(\dfrac{1000}{1999}\right)+f(1)\\&=999+f(1)\\&=999+\dfrac 2 3\\&=\dfrac {2999} 3\end{align}$$

---

$$\begin{align}f(x)+f(1-x)&=\dfrac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\dfrac{4^{1-x}}{4^{1-x}+2}\\&=\dfrac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\dfrac{\dfrac{4}{4^x}}{\dfrac{4}{4^x}+2}\\&=\dfrac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\dfrac 4 {2 \cdot4^x+4}\\&=\dfrac{4^x}{4^x+2}+\dfrac{\not{4}~~2}{\not2(4^x+2)}\\&=\dfrac{4^x+2}{4^x+2}\\&=1\end{align}$$

Comment: Do I look worried? :p

Comment: This is a strange dialogue.

Comment: And as rather rude

Comment: @kannappan no.but your comment to jeremy carlos made me think so