# Proving that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2006}f(i/2007)=1003$ if $f(x)=2008^{2x} /(2008 + 2008^{2x})$ from the 10th PMO

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, contest-math

From the [10th Philippine Mathematical Olympiad](https://pmo.ph/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/10th-PMO-Area-National-Stage-Questions-with-Answers.pdf):

> Let $f$ be the function defined by $$f(x) = \frac{2008^{2x}}{2008 + 2008^{2x}}, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$ Prove that $$f\left(\frac{1}{2007}\right) + f\left(\frac{2}{2007}\right) + \cdots + f\left(\frac{2005}{2007}\right) + f\left(\frac{2006}{2007}\right) = 1003.$$

The given solution was:

> We first show that the function satisfies the identity $f(x) + f(1 - x) = 1.$
> \begin{align*}f(1 - x) &= \frac{2008^{2(1-x)}}{2008 + 2008^{2(1 - x)}} \\\\ f(1 - x) &= \frac{2008^2 2008^{-2x}}{2008 + 2008^2 2008^{-2x}} \\\\ f(1 - x) &= \frac{2008}{2008^{2x} + 2008} \\\\\\\\ f(x) + f(1 - x) &= \frac{2008^{2x}}{2008 + 2008^{2x}} + \frac{2008}{2008^{2x} + 2008} \\\\ f(x) + f(1 - x) &= 1\end{align*}
> Pairing off the terms of the left-hand side of the desired equality into $$\left[f\left(\frac{1}{2007}\right) + f\left(\frac{2006}{2007}\right)\right] + \cdots + \left[f\left(\frac{1003}{2007}\right) + f\left(\frac{1004}{2007}\right)\right],$$ and applying the above identity solve the problem.

---

Now, this is not easily noticeable, at least for me. What I tried to do was approximate the sum through the integral $$I(a,b,c,d) = \int_c^d \frac{a^x}{a^x + b}\,dx$$ which, when solved, is equal to $$I(a,b,c,d) = \frac{1}{\ln a}\ln\left(\frac{a^d + b}{a^c + b}\right)$$ as I thought that $2006$ subdivisions is enough for the integral to approximate. The result of the integral will be rounded up to compensate for the difference. The given values in the problem are $a = 2008^{2/2007}$, $b = 2008$, $c = 1$, and $d = 2006$. By substitution, it should give us $$I = \frac{1}{\ln(2008^{2/2007})}\ln\left(\frac{2008^{4012/2007} + 2008}{2008^{2/2007} + 2008}\right).$$ Solving this gives us $$I = \frac{2005}{2} = 1002.5$$ and rounding this up gives us $1003$ as desired.<sup>1</sup>

---

My questions will be: How valid is this solution, and are there alternative solutions that does not use the given one?

---

Additional information:
[1] Solution for $I = \frac{1}{\ln(2008^{2/2007})}\ln\left(\frac{2008^{4012/2007} + 2008}{2008^{2/2007} + 2008}\right)$

> We know that $\ln (p/q) = \ln p - \ln q$. Hence, $$\ln\left(\frac{2008^{4012/2007} + 2008}{2008^{2/2007} + 2008}\right) = \ln(2008^{4012/2007} + 2008) - \ln(2008^{2/2007} + 2008).$$ Let $u = 2008^{4012/2007} + 2008$ and let $v = 2008^{2/2007} + 2008$. This means that we are solving for $\ln u - \ln v$.
>
> Notice that $u = 2008^{4012/2007} + 2007$ is equivalent to $u = 2008(2008^{2005/2007} + 1)$. Then, $$\ln u = \ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1).$$ Also, $v = 2008^{2/2007} + 2008$ is equivalent to $v = 2008(2008^{2005/2007} + 1)(2008^{-2005/2007})$. Then, \begin{align*}\ln v &= \ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) - \ln(2008^{-2005/2007}) \\ \ln v &= \ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) - \frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008.\end{align*}
> Solving for $\ln u - \ln v$, \begin{align*}\ln u - \ln v &= \ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) - \left(\ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) - \frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008\right) \\ \ln u - \ln v &= \ln 2008 + \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) - \ln 2008 - \ln(2008^{2005/2007} + 1) + \frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008 \\ \ln u - \ln v &= \frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008\end{align*}
> We are solving for $$I = \frac{1}{\ln(2008^{2/2007})}\ln\left(\frac{2008^{4012/2007} + 2008}{2008^{2/2007} + 2008}\right).$$ We know that $$\ln\left(\frac{2008^{4012/2007} + 2008}{2008^{2/2007} + 2008}\right) = \frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008,$$ hence, \begin{align*}I &= \frac{1}{\ln(2008^{2/2007})}\cdot\frac{2005}{2007}\ln 2008 \\ I &= \frac{2005}{2007}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{2}{2007}\ln 2008}\cdot \ln 2008 \\ I &= \frac{2005}{2007} \cdot \frac{2007}{2} \\ I &= \frac{2005}{2}. \qquad \blacksquare\end{align*}

Comment: I mean, it's a fair question, but in any case I think their solution is quite a bit easier and quicker. So the important thing is to take note of / remember *their* method. Especially if you want to improve at these Olympiad/ competition types of questions.

Comment: Simply put, your method is inadequate because you have not proven that your approximation has a sufficiently small error from the exact value.  You simply rationalize your approach by saying that some number of subdivisions of the integral are adequate but you have shown no work to justify that those errors do not accumulate to an extent that it would lead to a different answer.

Comment: @heropup Can I ask for hints how to prove that the integral has a small error compared to the actual answer?

Comment: How do you know the sum is an integer? That is, even if you know the error of the integral is about 1, for example, how do you justify that the result is $1003$ and not $1003.1$ or something else?

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht Isn't that what's given already and needs to be proven? Or is it that what I did was assume the result?

Comment: The Olympiad problem asks about the *exact* sum, not an approximation. So there's not much point using an approximate summation method unless you can also give the exact error of that method, which is generally not easy to do in a finite form. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: FWIW, estimating that sum via the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) gives the correct exact value, but even then you would need to prove that the error is zero.

Comment: @PM2Ring I will post the solution later. Still checking if there will be a better way.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123327/888233).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is invalid. Implicitly, I am trying to solve for the lower bound of the sum since it is the right Riemann sum of the integral I calculated. Even though the error is less than 1 which makes it okay to round up, it still doesn't prove that the sum *is* equal to $1003$.

In short, I just proved that $$1002.5 \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{2006}f\left(\frac{i}{2007}\right) \leq 1003$$ but not $$\sum_{i = 1}^{2006}f\left(\frac{i}{2007}\right) = 1003.$$